# Como usar un chat privado entre dos personas con WebSocket

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un chat con WebSockets en java pero entonces todos los que ingresan pueden ver esos mensajes, como puedo hacer que un chat sea privado para dos personas ?? 
Gracias por la ayuda a quien me regale almenos una indicacion la verdad no encontrado lo mas minimo sobre ese chat privado solo asi publico.

Mis webSockets son asi.

```
@OnOpen
    public void handleOpen(Session userSession) {
        chat.add(userSession);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void handleClose(Session userSession) {
        chat.remove(userSession);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void handleMessage(String message, Session userSession) throws IOException {
        username = (String) userSession.getUserProperties().get("username");
        if (username == null) {
            userSession.getUserProperties().put("username", message);
            // userSession.getBasicRemote().sendText(buildJsonData("En linea", "" + message));
        } else {
            if (!message.equals("")) {
                Iterator<Session> iterator = chat.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    iterator.next().getBasicRemote().sendText(buildJsonData(username, message));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String buildJsonData(String username, String message) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("message", "<strong class=\"text-purple\"> " + username + "</strong>" + " : " + message).build();
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        try (JsonWriter jsonWriter = Json.createWriter(stringWriter)) {
            jsonWriter.write(jsonObject);
        }
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Debes proporcionar algo de codigo para intentar ayudarte.

Comment: Hola @JGarnica ya adjunte mi codigo en la edicion de mi pregunta

Comment: [Mira](https://www.javatpoint.com/socket-programming) este enlace donde tienes un ejemplo en Java para crear un Cliente y un Servidor que se comunican entre ellos.